# No relevant source lines error. Compilation error

Tags: asp.net, .net

It has been answered before, but i don't know the way to find the exact solution. I took whole day to find the solution but i entirely stuck with this.

I was worked with my project nicely on day before yesterday. I designed many modules for doing my project further. AS usual i opened and started doing (I didn't get any errors) my project today in visual studio. To execute my old project(coding) once again, i checked in browser, as soon as i did, my face gone too bad :( because of this strange error. Error is,

**Compilation Error**

**Description** :  An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:**CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' could not be opened -- 'Error importing module 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' of assembly 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' -- An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '

**Source Error:**

```
[No relevant source lines]
```

**I did deleting temporary files in this area : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files. But again I'm getting the root folder when am running the project**

Any help, would be more and more helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The error message

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

means that there is an incompatibility in processor architecture. I think you installed either the 32- or 64-bit version of .NET and try to run your website in the opposite architecture.

You should install both the .NET framework versions, or change your application pool to use the right processor architecture.

Comment: Now am using in 32 bit. If am not wrong, you want me to install the .net framework for 64 bit also.Right ?

Comment: @gkrishy: You should check if my assumption is right. I think IIS runs in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Yes that's why am totally stuck. i was working nicely two days before, but I'm not getting today. :(